# Existence of Global Defining Function for Hypersurface

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, and $\Sigma$ a hypersurface of $M$. (That is, $\Sigma$ is smoothly a embedded subset of $M$ with codimension $1$.)

By a defining function for $\Sigma$, we mean some $f \in C^\infty(M)$ such that
$\Sigma = \{p: f(p) = 0\}$, and for any $s\in \Sigma$, $\nabla f(s) \neq 0$.

Suppose $\Sigma$ admits a global unit normal vector field.

Using the inverse function theorem for $\mathbb R^n$, I can show the existence of local defining functions, moreover I can then construct local defining functions satisfying $\nabla f(s) = n(s)$ for $s \in \Sigma$. Therefore, functions that are "defined locally on points nearby" will be "similar to first order". However, it is not true that we can simply stitch them together to form a global defining function, since there is no guarantee that the functions actually agree on their overlaps.

**Question:** Does the existence of a global unit normal vector field ensure the existence of a global defining function?

---

On second thought, every hypersurface of $\mathbb R^n$ should admit global unit normal vector fields. I usually do differential geometry in indefinite signatures where this isn't true in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You need a local defining function. This means that $\Sigma$ must have trivial normal bundle (equivalent to your condition, existence of a normal vector field). This is not always true: even oriented manifolds can have non-oriented, 1-sided submanifolds, the model case being $\Bbb{RP}^2 \subset \Bbb{RP}^3$ (or the same example 1 dimension down). Assuming the submanifold is oriented and the total space is oriented, then you can always oriented the normal bundle, and an oriented real line bundle is *trivial*, so this is sufficient to guarantee the global normal field.

2) If you have a global defining function, it cuts your manifold into $f^{-1}((-\infty, 0])$ and $f^{-1}([0, \infty))$. In particular, the complement of your hypersurface is disconnected. This is not always true: consider a circle inside of a torus (that doesn't just bound a disc); cut open along it and you reveal an annulus, which is connected.

Assuming your submanifold has trivial normal bundle and disconnected complement, you may always construct a global defining function: just make sure that you stay above $0$ on one side and less than $0$ on the other.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a reference for your second claim?

Comment: @Harambe What is the second claim? The bullet point (2)? The inverse image of (-infty, 0) and (0, infty) are disjoint open sets whose union is the complement of the hypersurface, so it is nonempty.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the statement: "with the added condition of having a disconnected complement, you may construct a global defining function". In (2) you show that a necessary condition is for the complement to be disconnected, but at the end you state the converse - ("trivial normal bundle and disconnected complement are sufficient").

Comment: @Harambe I don't know a reference (though of course I am sure this is well-known). The last sentence describes a picture which hints at the correct proof. Assume $\Sigma$ is connected; you can try to remove this assumption as an exercise. Let $U$ be a small neighborhood of $\Sigma$, small enough that you have a global defining function on $U$. Decompose the complement of $\Sigma$ as a disjoint union of two nonempty connected open sets $U_+$ and $U_-$, so that on $U$, the global defining function is positive on $U_+$ and negative on $U_-$. Pick a partition of unity subordinate to this cover.

Comment: Then $\eta_+ + f \eta - \eta_-$ is a global defining function.